# How to select multiple values in a single column in a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

```
Date            

12/4/2014  411,324,665
13/4/2014  422,334,567,7788
```

This is the result of the procedure, I have to select the invoices grouped by invoice date but how can I put the invoice numbers (of the invoices that have the same date) in a single column separated by a `,` ?

Please help and thank you

Comment: can you give me please the link where its asked and i will delete the quest

Comment: It says right at the top of the question: _This question already has an answer here:_ and then there's the link to the question (and the several good answers) that show you how to do this